# How to make an href dropdown item that does not reload the page with React-boostrap

Tags: reactjs, react-router, dropdown, react-bootstrap

I use a Dropdown with react-bootstrap.

in the dropdown item I fill in an href that will allow me to change page.

```
   <Dropdown>
    <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
     Menu
   </Dropdown.Toggle>

   <Dropdown.Menu>
     <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">aries</Dropdown.Item>
     <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">taurus</Dropdown.Item>

  </Dropdown.Menu>
 </Dropdown>
```

When I click on a dropdown item it completely reloads the page things I do not want.

```
    <Dropdown.Item>
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: `#/action-1`,
        }}
      >
        {' '}
        aries
      </Link>
      </Dropdown.Item>
```

the problem is that I get an error message that tells me:

```
 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.
```

Do you have a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<Dropdown.Item as={Link} to="/me">text here</Dropdown.Item>
```